# Create a Chrome extension like Grammarly

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, messenger

This is a weird question. However, I need help on this.

I want to build an extension which will show a button (like Grammarly extension shows) in any text field of any websites. Here is a screenshot of what I want.[image]

You see, I am pointing to the green button using the red arrow. I want to create an extension which will be able to show a button like this. After that, if a user clicks the button a callback function will be called.

Another question is it possible to create this same thing for any mobile app. like this when I am chatting using the browser this green button shows. Can I do the same thing when I chat in a messenger lie facebook or whatsapp?

Comment: 1) Yes, you can do it in the *content script*. 2) Mobile apps are a totally different area.

Comment: Could you please provide me some links for this ?

Comment: That's a huge topic. You can start with the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) or find a tutorial.